MS Word - Converting a custom footnote to a continuous numbered footnote list
I have some footnotes that I am editing (on a Mac), which have cross-references to the footnote (so copying and pasting the footnote text into a newly inserted footnote is not really an option).
How would I convert a custom footnote mark to a continuously numbered list (see below image)

I would like to be able to convert 8a, 9a, 9b, and 10a to their corresponding numbered footnote (without letters) such that the above footnotes would just number from 9–16:
8a --> 9
9a --> 11
9b --> 12
10a --> 14

I have heard that it's possible to convert the footnotes without copying and pasting by following these steps:

Place your cursor at the end of the content of footnote 8a.
Right-click on the footnote reference number (in this case, 8a) at the bottom of the page.
Select "Edit Field" from the context menu.
In the Field dialog box, change the "Reference type" to "Footnote" and set the "Field properties" to the desired footnote number (in this case, 9).
Click OK to apply the changes.

However, I am not able to confirm (at least on PC). For Mac, there is no option to edit field, and my understanding of the footnote dialog box (when right-clicking) is limited and has been futile in changing the footnote back to a continuous list.
What would I have to do on Mac to change the footnote mark back to a continuous list?

I tried the steps you listed on Mac, then on Windows. But I don't get "Edit field" on either, and that's probably because neither the footnote reference "at the bottom of the page" nor the footnote reference in the body of the text is a field code. AFAICS the only field code you might be able to select would be an additional reference to the note, i.e. a NOTEREF or perhaps an old FTNREF field. Could you get this procedure to work on Windows?
Personally, I'd probably assume a bit of VBA was needed. Probably already done by someone, but here's what I came up with as a starting point - test carefully before using it for real. This has had some rudimentary testing on Mac Word, but none on Windows Word, where it's possible the behaviour will be different.
I leave you to research how to install and use VBA macros on Mac Word.
Sub modifyfootnote()
' Click in a footnote and run this macro to replace a custom-numbered footnote
' by an auto-numbered footnote.

' When you have modified your footnotes, you will need to update any footnote cross-references
' that reference the modified footnotes,. at least if those cross-references are showing the footnote number.

' The easy way to do that would be to select the entire document at the end and update all
' the fields. But I suppose I would do that a little bit more often to reassure myself that the references
' were updating correctly.

' A Footnote.Range is the footnote text.
' A Footnote.Reference is the Range of the reference in the main text body (not the reference in the footnote)
Dim newfootnote As Word.Footnote
Dim oldrange As Word.Range
Dim referencerange As Word.Range
With Selection
  Select Case .Footnotes.Count
  Case 0:
     MsgBox "Please click in the body of a footnote."
  Case 1
    ' NB, if you triedto use a variable "oldfootnote" to point to the existing footnote,
    ' you will find that on insertion of the new one, the selection changes and in fact
    ' oldfootnote and newfootnote will point to the same footnote. Which isn't helpful.
    
    ' So instead we point oldrange to the range of the old footnote
    Set oldrange = Selection.Range.Footnotes(1).Range
    Set referencerange = Selection.Footnotes(1).Reference
    
    ' Inserting a new footnote immediately before the old footnote's reference appears to preserve the _Ref
    ' bookmark used for any cross-references to this bookmark
    referencerange.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart
    
    ' *all* auto-numbered footnotes will change to use whatever format you specify here.
    referencerange.FootnoteOptions.NumberStyle = wdNoteNumberStyleArabic
    Set newfootnote = referencerange.Footnotes.Add(referencerange, , "temptext")
    newfootnote.Range.FormattedText = oldrange.FormattedText
    oldrange.Footnotes(1).Delete
  Case Else
    MsgBox "You have selected more than one footnote. Please click in *just one* footnote."
  End Select
End With
End Sub

